# How to Gets All Subscribers Sent by EmailName

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

How can you combine the Job and Sent table in SFMC so you can get results of SubscriberKeys of everyone who has ever been sent that email by EmailName?

Answer (score 0):

The `JobID` is the relates activity views according to the [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) documentation on the SFMC help site.

So to retrieve all SubscriberKeys by EmailName you could do something along these lines:

```
select
j.emailName
,s.subscriberkey
from _job j
inner join _sent s on (s.jobid = j.jobid)
where j.emailname = 'Getting started with the SFMC wiki'
```

These views only hold activity for the past 6 months.